# XQuery get node without namespace

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML with a namespace:

```
<namespace:root>
  <namespace:node>
    <namespace:subnode>value</namespace:subnode>
  </namespace:node>
</namespace:root>
```

I need to perform an XQuery to get, as an output, the same XML or a subnode, without namespace:

```
<root>
  <node>
    <subnode>value</subnode>
  </node>
</root>
```

Is there a XQuery syntax for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive function for stripping all prefixes from element and attribute names:

```
declare function local:strip-namespaces($node as node()) as node()* {
  if($node instance of element()) then (
    element { local-name($node) } {
      for $attribute in $node/@*
      return attribute { local-name($attribute) } { $attribute },
      for $child in $node/node()
      return local:strip-namespaces($child)
    }
  ) else (
    $node
  )
};

let $xml :=
  <namespace:root xmlns:namespace='URI' namespace:id='123'>
    <namespace:node>
      <namespace:subnode>value</namespace:subnode>
    </namespace:node>
  </namespace:root>
return local:strip-namespaces($xml)
```

Comment: Christian Grün, I tested your answer in BaseX 9.3.1 It emits the following: <root id="123">
  <node>
    <subnode/>
  </node>
</root>, the **subnode** element is missing value in the test case.

Comment: You meant to say that the `value` text node was not included in the result, right? I have slightly rewritten the solution, I hope it’s ok now.

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side!